# Is there a good, readable way to define simple nested classes in C#

Tags: c#, json

I'm an experienced C# software engineer. I've read the docs and dug through blogs. I suspect the answer is "No, C# doesn't support that", but it's worth asking here:

Suppose I have a JSON data description like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "name": {
      "first_name": "Fred",
      "last_name": Smith,
    },
    "address": {
      "street": "123 Main Street",
      "city": "Anytown",
      "state": "CA"
    }
}
```

JSON makes it super easy to create deeply nested data structures. But in order to represent this same data structure in C#, I apparently need to define a separate class for EVERY nested structure, like this:

```
private class Data {
  public Name name { get; set; }
  public Address address { get; set; }
}

private class name {
  public string first_name { get; set; }
  public string last_name { get; set; }
}

private class Address {
  public string street { get; set; }
  public string city { get; set; }
  public string state { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any way to simplify this code to approach the simplicity of the JSON representation?

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for. You need to define the structure _somehow_. If not with a class, then with what? Is your problem that you need 3 classes? Or that the classes are not nested?

Comment: Just wondering, but what would a simplified approach look like to you? Are there examples you can find in other languages that are good examples?

Comment: Dynamic + ExpandoObject. But it is not recommended.

Comment: Atm, its looks like something that would be useful to have in c# in the future.  Especially when we need to call external rest endpoints and don't really want to create c# classes.  Dynamic + Expando mentioned by @AlexanderPetrov can get you there to some point.  But its not very clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confounding two different concepts. The JSON you included is defining the *object*. The C# equivalent of this might look like this, using anonymous types:

```
new
{
    data = new
    {
        name = new
        {
            first_name = "Fred",
            last_name = "Smith"
        },
        address = new
        {
            street = "123 Main Street",
            city = "Anytown",
            state = "CA"
        }
    }
}
```

The C# code you posted defined the *types*. The equivalent of this would have to be done in a language like TypeScript, since JavaScript doesn't have types yet. The TypeScript would look like this:

```
type response = {
  data: {
    name: {
      first_name: string,
      last_name: string
    },
    address: {
      street: string,
      city: string,
      state: string
    }
  }
}
```

There isn't a simple syntax for declaring a nested C# type like this. You *can* declare C# classes nested inside of other classes, but that doesn't let you declare the types inline with the property name like TypeScript does.

If you are trying to *consume* JSON in C#, and don't care to create strong types like the C# code above, you can avoid creating types entirely: Just deserialize the JSON to a `dynamic` type, or use a type like `JToken` and access its pieces using strings. (Details on how to do this will depend on your serialization framework.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to build new types that are easier to read just use something like notepadd ++ and make a json object first then use a conversion tool to auto have it made into c# objects.

Here's another way :
What you could do is look into Generating an Avro Schema from C#

If you are looking to kind of automate the process you can do the following
https://www.thecodebuzz.com/generate-avro-schema-from-json/

Answer (score 0):

If the classes are very dependent on each other, for example, `name` and `addresss` don't make sense outside `data`, you can define them inside `data`, as nested classes. You do not save code, but it is more encapsulated.

In that case, you do this:

```
private class Data
{
    public Name name { get; set; }
    public Address address { get; set; }

    #region Nested classes

    public class Name
    {
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address
    {
        public string street { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

With the region you can collapse that code and get your `Data` class less overloaded.